# If there exists a diffeomorphism between two surfaces, what is the relation between Laplace-Beltrami operators on the surfaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, surfaces

Let $S(0)$ and $S(t)$ be a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose there is a diffeomorphism
$F^0_t:S(0) \to S(t)$. Suppose we have the Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta_{S(\cdot)}$. Let $u:S(t) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function.

I want a formula for $\Delta_{S(t)}u(x)$ in terms of $\Delta_{S(0)}$ and $u(F^0_t(y))$ where $x=F^0_t(y)$:

$$\Delta_{S(t)}u(x) = ??$$

By nice I am hoping for something that does not involve huge sums explicitly. I'm sure this kind of issue is well-established but I can't find anything.

---

Note that the surface gradient is defined as
$$\nabla_{S(\cdot)}v = \nabla v- \nabla v \cdot \nu(\cdot)\nu(\cdot)$$
where $\nu(\cdot)$ is a unit normal vector of $S(\cdot)$, and the Laplace-Beltrami is the surface divergence of the surface gradient as expected.

Comment: Is your function u defined only on S(t), or is it also defined on S(0)?

Comment: @XipanXiao It is defined only on $S(t)$ (but of course we can use the map $F^0_t$ to obtain a pullback function that is defined on $S(0)$).

Comment: Hi. I would be interested in the kinematics of hypersurfaces (and in the notation you used as well). Do you recommend some book/paper/whatever? Have a look at this (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764546/given-a-diffeomorphism-between-two-surfaces-is-there-an-expression-for-the-pull), maybe you can help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: $\Delta_tu(x)$ cannot be written strictly in terms of $\Delta_0(u\circ F^0_t)(y)$ and $u(x)$; the difference $\Delta_tu(x)-\Delta_0(u\circ F^0_t)(y)$ will also depend on the (non-Laplacian) derivatives of $u$ in a nontrivial way, unless of course $F^0_t$ is an isometry.

Comment: You can get a clearer picture of what's going on by pulling back the metric from $S(t)$ to $S(0),$ after which you're just trying to relate the Laplace-Beltrami operators of two different metrics on the same manifold. There's no nice relationship in general.

Comment: @Kajelad But it can be written in terms of the divergence of some matrix dotted with the gradient, no?

Comment: @StopUsingFacebook Not necessarily; It will in general be a linear combination of first and second derivatives.

Comment: @Kajelad, do you mind providing a reference for how this can be written as the linear combination of the two? Is there any reference addressing this problem in any level?

Comment: @Cupitor One way to see this is from the expression for the Laplacian in local coordinates:$$\Delta u=g^{ij}\partial_i\partial_ju-g^{jk}\Gamma^i{}_{jk}\partial_iu$$Choosing different metrics $g$ and $g'$, the difference $(\Delta-\Delta')u$ can depend on any of the derivatives of $u$ which show up in that expression.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering the question. From what I understand you consider a simple example where the diffeomorphism is keeping the manifold intact and changing it's metric. But isn't $u$ here a real-valued function? I mean no doubt $
(\Delta-\Delta')u$ will depend on the derivatives of $u$, no?