# Given a diffeomorphism between two surfaces, is there an expression for the pullback of the covariant derivative of a vector field?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, classical-mechanics, connections

Let $A$ and $B$ be two surfaces (smooth enough) in an affine space $M$ with metric $g$. Let $g^A$, $g^B$ be the metric tensors on the two surfaces induced by $g$, and $\nabla^A$, $\nabla^B$ the Levi-Civita connections on the two surfaces. Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a diffeomorphism.

I'm wondering if, given a vector field $X^B$ on $B$, there is an expression for $f^* (\nabla^{B} X^B)$. I think it should be something including $\nabla^A(f^*X^B)$, but I can't find it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Differentials pull back, vector fields push forward. So no, unless you use $f^{-1}$ (which is perfectly defined, and smooth).

Comment: Yes, I'm using $f^{-1}$, in order to extend the pullback definition to a (1,1) tensor field.

Comment: You could express it as $\nabla^{f^*B} F^* X^B$, i.e. the covariant derivative with respect to the pulled-back connection.

Comment: Actually I was thinking to something including the connection $\nabla^A$ already defined, maybe using the fact that both $g^A$ and $g^B$ are induced by the same metric.

Comment: @Gaff: The fact that they are both induced by the same ambient metric is irrelevant: Any two Riemannian manifolds embed isometrically in some Euclidean space.

Comment: @studiosus: Yes but since we're not considering them with any two metrics, but with two specific and linked ones, I'm expecting some kind of result.

Comment: In what way are your metrics "linked"?

Comment: They are both induced by $g$, this should mean something. Considering the surfaces as regular submanifolds of the Euclidean space, $g^A$ and $g^B$ are simply two restrictions of the same tensor field. This "link" can be expressed using charts (considering two "preferred coordinates" relative to the two surfaces), but with components I can't get to anything.

Comment: The fact that they are both induced by the same ambient metric g means exactly nothing, see my comment above. You can as well just consider two arbitrary metrics with LC connections and ask what's the relation between them. They differ by a 0-th order operator (difference of their Crystoffel symbols). That's the best you can say.